# Controlling the function names of C# Properties

Tags: script#

I have this code in C# (as an ImportLibrary):

```
[IgnoreNamespace]
[Imported]
public class MyClass
{
    public object Value
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

and I then comsume the class like this:

```
myClass.Value = 0;
obj val = myClass.Value;
```

Everthing is fine and compiles - so that is good :) However, the result is something like this:

```
myClass.set_value(0);
var val = myClass.get_value();
```

of what I really wanted was:

```
myClass.setValue(0);
var val = myClass.getValue();
```

So, NO underscore (_) and a capital letter. How can I control this? I've tried with [ScriptName("Value")], but with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Right now there isn't support for that pattern of properties. You'd simply have to have methods - GetValue and SetValue.

Its changeable of course, but I fear creating endless set of permutations for all the possible different patterns when looking at script generation overall, rather than just property syntax. I actually am not attached to "get_" ... it was simply to separate what is the actual name vs. what was tacked on, as well as to use the same pascal-case to camel-case routine already in place ... so open to the idea of switching to just "get" but it would need to apply to "add_" and "remove_" as well for events. Why don't you open an issue on the script# github repo (https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp), and see if there is concensus for changing?

So to understand the motivation, is it because you're trying to generate script that something else existing is calling and hence must be called "getValue"... or is this stemming from preference.

Comment: Side comment - if this is must-have, you could also fork/make the change locally, though I'll also be upfront and also mention that a number of things in the compiler are changing and will be changing over the coming months to bring some significant improvements.

Comment: Hi @NikhilK. Thank you for the quick answer. Yes, I'm wrapping an existing API (Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK) and therefore the names must be getValue etc... But I'll stick the the "method"-method for now, but will put in an issue to be able to override "get" and "set" of properties. Once again, Thanks!

Comment: Do post an issue. I might be able to address for the next release, or the one after that. I mistook that you wanted this for script you were generating. However it seems its really for script you're importing, where it makes a lot of sense.